# Display class in view from selected list ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a listbox of licenseplates, and when I select one of the items in the list, I want to retrive the rest of the information about the licenseplate and display it in my view.

I have filled my listbox with only the licenseplatenumber from a list that fills upp with the whole datatable. When I select the licenseplatenumber I want to display all the information from the list that I have made.

I have tried to use `@Html.displayfor` and then when I select an item I want to display the brand of that car. I don't really understand how to retrive it and to display it

This is my Model:

```
 public class AdminCar 
    {
        public int CarID { get; set; }
        public string LicensePlateNumber { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public long BirthOfDate { get; set; }
        public int VehicleFines { get; set; }
        public bool IsStolen { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
        public ActionResult CarInfo()
        {
            var CarService = new CarService();
            List<Core.Entities.Response.CoreCar> cars = CarService.ListOfCars();

            List<AdminCar> aCar = new List<AdminCar>();

            foreach (var item in cars)
            {
                AdminCar car = new AdminCar
                {
                    LicensePlateNumber = item.LicensePlateNumber,
                    Brand = item.Brand,
                    Color = item.Color,
                    Model = item.Model,
                    Firstname = item.Firstname,
                    Lastname = item.Lastname,
                    BirthOfDate = item.BirthOfDate,
                    VehicleFines = item.VehicleFines,
                    IsStolen = item.IsStolen,
                };
                aCar.Add(car);

            }
            return View(aCar);
        }
```

This is in my View:

```
<select name="listbox" id="CarSelected">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.LicensePlateNumber">
            @item.LicensePlateNumber                                
        </option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you use ajax call to get information from server

$('#CarSelected').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'controller/action',
      type:'Get',
      data:{LicensePlateNumber:$('#CarSelected').val()},
      success:function(infoCar){
       // there update info of car by jquery
     }
    });
});

Comment: okey, i have field in my database called Brand, how do i call it and display it in the view? dont get how i manage to show the info in the view

Comment: I Cant help you in your code you may using EF or Ado Or any tools to get data from database but can help you by in your controller add action GetCarInfo(string LicensePlateNumber){ connect to database and get data by select info from tableCar where LicensePlateNumber = val and  return JsonResult(data,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)}

Comment: i have a list in my controller which have all the items in Carinfo table. And i fill the listbox with just the licenseplatenumber. so when i select an item in the listbox i just wanna call on the entire list so i can display it. like where licenseplatenumber == carID. then i display
licenseplate
color
model
just dont understand how iam going do display it in the view.
i already have a list with all the info just wanna present it when the licensplate is selected